# Not able to understand the use of .mode() in python

Tags: python, pandas, series, mode

I have a requirement where I need to find out the most popular start hour. 
Following is the code that has helped me in finding the correct solution.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# bunch of code comes
# here
# that help in reaching the following steps

df = pd.read_csv(CITY_DATA[selected_city])

# convert the Start Time column to datetime
df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])

# extract hour from the Start Time column to create an hour column
df['hour'] = df['Start Time'].dt.hour

# extract month and day of week from Start Time to create new columns
df['month'] = df['Start Time'].dt.month

df['day_of_week'] = df['Start Time'].dt.weekday_name

# find the most popular hour
popular_hour = df['hour'].mode()[0]
```

here is a sample o/p that i get when i try to run this query

> "print(df['hour'])"

```
0         15
1         17
2          8
3         13
4         14
5          9
6          9
7         17
8         16
9         17
10         7
11        17
Name: hour, Length: 300000, dtype: int64
```

The o/p that i get when i use

> print(type(df['hour']))

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

The value of the most popular start hour is stored in popular_hour which is equal to "17" (It is the correct value)

However I am not able to understand the part of .mode()[0]

> What does this .mode() do and why [0] ?
>
> And will the same concept be to calculate popular month and popular day of the week also irrespective of their datatype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mode` returns a Series:

```
df.mode()
0    17
dtype: int64
```

From this, you take the first item by calling

```
df.mode()[0]
17
```

Note that a Series is always returned, and sometimes if there are multiple values for mode, they are all returned:

```
pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]).mode()
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

You would still take the first value each time and discard the rest. Note that when multiple modes are returned, they are *always* sorted.

Read the documentation on [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) for more info.